# Recursion depth error when using BeautifulSoup with multiprocessing pool map

Tags: python, multiprocessing, beautifulsoup

I have been using BeautifulSoup for parsing html files, while all the scripts i write work good but slow. So i am experimenting on using multiprocessing pool of workers along with BeautifulSoup so my program can run more faster (I have like 100,000 - 1,000,000 html files to open). The script i wrote is more complex but i have written down an small example down here. I am trying to do something like this and i keep getting the error

**'RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object'**

**Edited Code**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from multiprocessing import Pool
def extraction(path):
   soup=BeautifulSoup(open(path),"lxml")
   return soup.title

pool=Pool(processes=4)
path=['/Volume3/2316/http/www.metro.co.uk/news/852300-haiti-quake-victim-footballers-stage-special-tournament/crawlerdefault.html','/Volume3/2316/http/presszoom.com/story_164020.html']
print pool.map(extraction,path)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

After doing some search and digging through some posts, i got to know that the error is occurring because BeautifulSoup is exceeding the depth of the python interpreter stack. I tried to raise the limit and run the same program ( i went up to 3000) but the error remains same. I stopped raising the limit because the problem is with BeautifulSoup when opening the html files.

Using multiprocessing with BeautifulSoup will speed my execution time, but i am not able to figure out how to apply it to open the files.

Does anyone have any other approach on how to use BeautifulSoup with multiprocessing or how to come over these kind of errors ?

Any kind of help will be appreciated, i am sitting for hours trying to fix it and understand why i am getting the error.

**Edit**

I tested the above code with the files i have given in the paths and i got the same RuntimeError as above

The files can be accessed here (http://ec2-23-20-166-224.compute-1.amazonaws.com/sites/html_files/)

Comment: The script above does not generate the error you describe for me. Could you paste the simplest script that you've actually tested, and that _does_ generate this error?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply..i just tested the code with the above html pages i have given in the link and i got the error "RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while pickling an object " Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3):

I think the reason is the returning of the whole `soup.title`-object. It seems, it all the `children` and `parent` elements and their children and parents and so on are analysed in this moment, and this raises the recursion error.

If the content of the object is what you need, you can simply call the **str**-method:

```
return soup.title.__str__()
```

Unfortunatly, this means, you don’t have access to all the other information provided by the bs4-library anymore.